# Why is redux on the shoulders of the frontender when it's the backend's job?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I know what redux is, and why it is needed, and even how it works. But by God, I can't understand why something that stores data should be on the font side, when everything that stores data is a matter for Beck? I use React

Answer (score 2):

Because Redux runs on the Browser, which is considered Frontend.

Also, Redux does not store data any more than a single variable would. In fact, a redux store internally only **is** a single variable.
Redux just gives you patterns to modify that variable in a safe & observable way and access it (with react-redux) throughout your application.

But it has nothing to do with Backend, which would imply servers, not browsers.